# How to log the error of an electron windows application : "A javacript error occured in the main process"

Tags: windows, logging, electron

I created an electron app. I get this error.

[image]

I know that it is due to a native lib not being built against the correct platform. My problem is that the name of the lib doesn't appear in the error message. I tried to run the app in the cmd, but there is no log there. I tried event viewer and I tried to install Process Monitor to detect the errors, but I didn't succeed to find the error log, and I end up with no idea about how to find the complete error message.

I even tried `"C:/path/to/my/app.exe" > log.txt 2> errorlog.txt` but the 2 files were empty...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I discovered how to debug a program on Windows... Don't use Windows. I switched to Ubuntu, installed wine, ran the faulty project, and directly got the complete error message. Turns out that the culprit was ref-napi. I solved the original issue [this way](https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/node-ffi-napi/issues/144)